how to update sharepoint online list icon and color using pnp powershell or any script?
What is the best way to update list icon using any script? I already enabled client script for the site and tried below command to update the list icon but no luck.
Set-PnPPropertyBagValue -Key "_ListIcon" -Value "Calendar"
after running below command, results showing that it has value Calendar but sharepoint list icon was not updated.
Get-PnPPropertyBag -Key "_ListIcon"  # this command for to get property bag values
any references would be appreciated.


If the image is in the assets library, you could do similar to what is done in this script.
link

You need to upload your icon to Site Assest first, and then use the Temp command below to update the list icon.
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
 
#Get the List
$List = Get-PnPList "Documents"
 
#Update Icon for the list
$List.ImageUrl = "/_layouts/15/images/itdl.png"
$List.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery

The color of the list is usually related to the theme of the site. You can customize your theme and apply it based on this documentation: SharePoint site theming.
